# Maximum length of string argument in java processbuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I know there is a string limitation when we execute application from command line / terminal which depends on the OS.
But if we use the Java ProcessBuilder to execute application, is there any maximum string length to be passed as argument in the java ProcessBuilder ?

```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
```

Thanks

Comment: To me, this smells fishy. Are you trying to pass huge files as text?

Comment: we dont pass more than 4 args in commandline rather keep everything in file and provide file name as single arg

Comment: @SBI something like that, i want to pass large JSON string, maybe around 1 Mega Bytes.

Comment: Terrible idea. Write them to a file and then stream them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at ProcessBuilder source code the process creation is delegated to a OS specific `java.lang.ProcessImpl`.

For instance the Windows version of `ProcessImpl` calls [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Win API, passing the commandline string. The documentation for parameter `lpCommandLine`states:  "The maximum length of this string is 32,768 characters".

So yes there will be OS specific length limitations, based on the OS function to create the process.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesnt restrict the length. You can pass n parameters but it depends on the OS.

Description from Java Doc [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.lang.String...%29)

> Constructs a process builder with the specified operating system program and arguments. This is a convenience constructor that sets the process builder's command to a string list containing the same strings as the command array, in the same order. It is not checked whether command corresponds to a valid operating system command.

Usually we don't pass more than 4 args in commandline rather keep everything in file and provide file name as single argument and use the config file.