# Jar file not accepting huge string in java

Tags: java, jar, parameters

What is the best way of passing a string (arg1 in case of code below) with about 800K characters (yes, that's a huge number) to a java jar. Following is the code I am using to invoke the jar file:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(jrePath+"/bin/java -jar C:/folder/myjar.jar methodName" + arg1);
```

ALternately, how can I create a jar file to accept one `String` input and one `byte[]` input in main{ in `void main(String args[])`}

Or any other ideas? The requirement is to somehow pass the huge `String`/`byte[]` of `String` to a java jar file that I am creating

Comment: Maybe you should use a temporary file instead of a `String`. Then have the program parse that file.

Comment: I highly doubt that this problem is from the jar file. It is more likely that you command line disallows this ridiculous long input. As written above, use a file instead.

Comment: You could also possibly write the data to the program's standard input.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202468/maximum-length-of-string-argument-in-java-processbuilder), there is a maximum argument length set by the operating system. Seeing as this argument is `800K` characters, its fairly safe to say that you have exceeded this max value on most computers. To get around this, you can write `arg1` to a temp file using the built in API:

```
final File temp;
try {
    temp = File.createTempFile("temp-string", ".tmp");
} catch (final IOException e){
    //TODO handle error
    return;
}
try (final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp))) {
    writer.write(arg1);
} catch (final IOException e){
    //TODO handle error
    return;
}
try {
    // run process and wait for completion
    final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        jrePath + "/bin/java -jar C:/folder/myjar.jar methodName " +
        temp.getAbsolutePath());
    final int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    if (exitCode != 0) {
        //TODO handle error
    }
} catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e){
    //TODO handle error
    return;
}
if (!file.delete()) {
    //TODO handle error
}
```