# ArrayList as stdin to ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process

I have a list of strings that I want to stream through system commands via `ProcessBuilder`; each string is the equivalent of a line of input passed to the system command as `stdin`. For example, if my list is `["foo" "bar" "spam"]`, I'm looking for the rough equivalent of:

```bash
echo -e "foo\nbar\nspam" | grep 'foo'
```

I don't know how to turn a list of strings to an input suitable for `ProcessBuilder`. This is some draft code:

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
input.add("foo");
input.add("bar");
input.add("spam");

List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
cmd.add("grep");
cmd.add("foo");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command(cmd);

// *** Some magic here to pass `input` to ProcessBuilder, like: ***
pb.inputFromList(input);

// Then process and collect output (this I'm ok):
Process p= pb.start();
BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
// Do something with reader which now contains only "foo".
```

I could write the input list to a temporary file first and use that in the system command `cmd`, but I would prefer to avoid that.

Also, I'm not dead set on using `ProcessBuilder`, any other option is ok.

---

**UPDATE** I made some progress following @rzwitserloot answer. The code below works as long as the `inputList` of strings is not too big. However, as anticipated by @rzwitserloot, it locks once `inputList` has ~40000 elements.

Now I'm stuck again. If I include the line

```
pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
```

I get `java.io.IOException: Stream closed`. I tried to implement the other option not using `pb.redirectInput(...)` to no avail.

```java
List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Small input is ok. If i > 50000 it blocks
    inputList.add("foo");
    inputList.add("bar");
}

List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
cmd.add("grep");
cmd.add("foo");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command(cmd);
// pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();

OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();

int i = 0;
for(String line : inputList){
    stdin.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    stdin.write('\n');
    i++;
    System.err.println(i);
}
stdin.close();

BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    System.err.println(line);
}
reader.close();
p.waitFor();
```

---

**UPDATE 2** This is far more complex than I thought and I wonder whether I should fall back to the temporary file solution. But let's try again.

The function below is supposed to take a list of strings as input and a system command with its arguments. It returns a list resulting from streaming the input list through the system command.

```java
public static ArrayList<String> execSystemCommand(List<String> inputList, List<String> cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command(cmd);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // Do I need this?
    Process p = pb.start();

    ArrayList<String> results= new ArrayList<String>();
    
    Thread readerThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    results.add(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);
        }
    });
    readerThread.start();
    
    OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();

    for(String line : inputList){
        stdin.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        stdin.write('\n');
    }
    stdin.close();
    p.waitFor();
    
    return results;
}
```

and here's a test case:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    // Input list is [foo0, foo1, ..., foo99999]
    List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        inputList.add("foo" + i);
    }
    
    List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
    cmd.add("grep");
    cmd.add("foo");

    ArrayList<String> results = Utils.execSystemCommand(inputList, cmd);
    
    System.out.println("Size:" + results.size());
    System.out.println("First element:" + results.get(0));
    System.out.println("Last element:" + results.get(results.size() - 1));
}
```

I can see an erratic behaviour as on different executions I get different results, for example:

```
Size:93166
First element:foo0
Last element:foo93165

Size:100000
First element:foo0
Last element:foo99999

Size:93622
First element:foo0
Last element:foo96351
```

So, still not there.

---

For the record: I'm not using this to run `grep`. Here `grep` is just for example.

Comment: @user16320675 Thanks, I had a look around before posting and I'm a bit confused. If you could add an answer to fill in the part `pb.inputFromList(input)` that would be great!

Comment: There's a puzzling disconnect here: if you're looking for the equivalent of `echo -e "foo\nbar\nspam" | grep 'foo'` why would you want to discard most of the potential input? One of the problems here is that you're not stating your actual [goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/15-smart-questions) so this could be an 'XY question'

Comment: @g00se I just made a toy example to illustrate the problem. I have list of strings that I want to parse through a system command as if the list of strings is a file with one string per line.

Comment: It should be mentioned that one should *never* use ProcessBuilder to run `grep`, because Java can do everything grep can do. See the [java.util.regex package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).

Comment: So, the command is _grep_ and you want to _grep foo_, _grep bar_, _grep spam_?

Comment: @Reilas Not quite - I want the equivalent of `cat in.txt | grep foo` where `in.txt` contains "foo", "bar", "spam", each word on its own line. However, instead of feeding grep with `cat ... |` I want to feed it with a ArrayList of strings. (And again, grep is just to make the example easy).

Comment: *I want the equivalent of ...* As @VGR said, that functionality would be easily replicable by simply using the `List` of values directly. e.g. `input.stream().filter(s ->s.contains("foo"))...`

Comment: @g00se Again: grep is here just for example and maybe the phrasing of the question doesn't make it clear. The question is: Use an ArrayList as stdin to a system command (e.g. grep).

Comment: @dariober, it appears there is a maximum input for ProcessBuilder, platform specific.   _https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202756/17758716_

Answer (score 1):

The way 'standard in' and 'standard out' works is: They are *byte streams*. A sequence of bytes, sent whenever you want, with one out-of-band concept called 'ending it' (closing the stream / EOF). You can't start sending this data until *after* the app has been launched; after all, you can send a few gigabytes through (you wouldn't want to pre-load that), or even, an infinite supply of something (let's say an endless stream of one values; the linux `/bin/true` command, if you pipe it to something, would do exactly that: Stuff ones into the standard in of the thing you pipe it to, *endlessly*.

```
Process p = pb.start();
try (var out = p.getOutputStream()) {
  for (String in : inputList) {
    out.write(in.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    out.write('\n');
  }
}
```

does the job. As I said, this stuff is bytes, not chars, so we have to convert, and converting means we need a charset. You might want to prefer the platform default instead:

```
Charset platformDefault = Charset.defaultCharset();
try {
  platformDefault = Charset.forName(System.getProperty("native.encoding"));
} catch (Exception ignore) {}

// then you can do:
out.write(in.getBytes(platformDefault);
```

Ordinarily you wouldn't want to mess with 'platform default encoding' (just go with UTF-8, which is standard, even, on JDK17+, but it doesn't hurt to explicitly say it, makes your code more readable and avoids confusion as it isn't a guaranteed default on JDK11), but if your app is explicitly designed to interact with other non-JVM-based applications on the system, they tend to want platform default.

### But, careful - this is deadlock prone!

If you send a ton of data, well, while you're sending data to that app, many apps will start responding data back to you. Eventually a buffer might get full: The other application will pause, wanting somebody to pull whatever it is emitting to standard out away from it before it continues, and in this code, you aren't doing that.

This would then cause **deadlock**: Your java app never gets to the phase where you read `p.getInputStream()`'s data out, and the other app never lets your java app send more (i.ee those `out.write` calls will be pausing forever).

The only solution to this is to either tell the process to just 'merge' your java process's standard out (call `.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)` *before* `start()`ing), or fire up a second thread that calls `.getInputStream()` and reads the bytes out of that (or start a thread to send your list of strings - either one needs to be done by a separate thread).

### EDIT: How to use a thread

Run your reader code as:

```
Thread readerThread = new Thread(() -> {
  try {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.err.println(line);
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);
  }
});

readerThread.start();
```

and do that before starting your `p.getOutputStream()` part.

Comment: As others have pointed out, [Process.outputWriter()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#outputWriter()) and [Process.inputReader()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#inputReader()) take care of using the native encoding.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I made some progress but I'm stuck with the deadlock problem (I think). I edited my question, any help much appreciated.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thanks, but I'm afraid I still don't get it... Can you check my UPDATE 2 in the question?

Comment: All you're missing is to allow that reader thread to finish its work. Just call `readerThread.join()`, _then_ `return results;`. (You'd think `p.waitFor()` does that, but for a bunch of reasons, that's not good enough).

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited (platform specific) default buffer size to stdin, stdout and stderr. Failing to consume output can lead to deadlock.

In your case your for loop over `stdin.write` is being read by `grep` which generates stdout. This stdout blocks when full because your stdout reader code is not reached until after the stdin for loop ends (you can confirm with jstack trace).

A similar deadlock can happen with independent stdout / stderr streams which are read one after the other and when the second is filled first. Nearly all SO examples of `ProcessBuilder` don't actually work reliably.

When the stdin stream you send to the sub-process is large is must be in a separate thread to the consumer of stdout (and also stderr if that is not redirected to stdin). So run this part of your code in a background thread and you should avoid the deadlock you have now hit for large inputList:

```
for(String line : inputList){

 stdin.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    stdin.write('\n');
    i++;
    System.err.println(i);
}
stdin.close();
```

In addition you need redirect error to output or inheritIO as in @rzwitserloot answer with the code to consume stdout before calling `p.waitFor()`.

If you do add any background tasks to provide stdin or consume stdout/stderr as a `Thread` or via `ExecutorService` then don't forget to wait for the actions by adding `thread.join()` or `future.get()` before calling `p.waitFor()`.

Another way to avoid large stdin deadlock is to write stdin to a file and setup ProcessBuilder to read stdin from that file.

Comment: Can you check UPDATE 2 in the question? Any help much appreciated - *write stdin to a file and setup ProcessBuilder to read stdin from that file*, yes, I have considered that, but I thought it clunky and inefficient. However, I also thought reading from stdin was much simpler than all this.

Comment: You don't know for sure that the background thread has finished, you need `readerThread.join()` before `p.waitFor()`